# Streaming input for speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, audio-streaming, speech-to-text, pyaudio

How to extract feature from stream of sound?

I tried to use `htk`, `pytorch`, or other libraries for filterbank.
But they need loading wav file.

I want to process directly microphone input by pyaudio.

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=44100, input=True)
while stream.is_active(): 
    input = stream.read(CHUNK)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use librosa, pretty standard library. You need stream feature:

https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stream.html

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=44100, input=True)
stream = librosa.stream(stream,
                         block_length=256,
                         frame_length=2048,
                         hop_length=2048)
for y_block in stream:
     m_block = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y_block, sr=sr,
                                              n_fft=2048,
                                              hop_length=2048,
                                              center=False)
```